# In Google App Engine, is fetch(100) more expensive than fetch(20) where there are only 20 entities?

Tags: google-app-engine, fetch

When fetching a query, is there a penalty for setting the fetch limit to 100 versus setting it to 20, when there are less than 20 matching entities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, setting a higher limit than the number of entities has no effect; the cost of the fetch is related only to the number of entities actually retrieved.